# RSpec spy on helper method from another helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got a rails helper - FirstHelper:

```
module FirstHelper
  def a_method_from_first_helper(args)
    # do something with args and return a value
  end
end
```

that I call in a second helper SecondHelper:

```
module ProjectHelper
  def a_method_from_second_helper(project)
    a_method_from_first_helper(args)
  end
end
```

The `a_method_from_first_helper` method is thoroughly tested in its spec. In my `second_helper_spec.rb` I want to be able to stub the `a_method_from_first_helper` method from the `FirstHelper` so that I can spy on it and check that it is called with the correct arguments.

I can't work out how to do this - I've tried all sorts of ways - this is my current attempt

```
require 'rails_helper'
include FirstHelper

RSpec.describe SecondHelper, :type => :helper do
  describe '#a_method_from_second_helper' do
    it 'calls a_method_from_first_helper with the correct arguments' do
      spy = instance_double('a_method_from_first_helper')
      allow(helper).to receive('a_method_from_first_helper').and_return(spy)
      a_method_from_second_helper
      expect(spy).to have_received(correct_arguments)
    end
  end
end
```

But this doesn't override the method from the `FirstHelper`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is easier than this, because the expectation and the spy can be setup in one step:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SecondHelper, :type => :helper do
  SecondHelper.module_eval do
    extend FirstHelper
  end

  describe '#a_method_from_second_helper' do
    it 'calls a_method_from_first_helper with the correct arguments' do
      expected_args = nil # the expected args come here
      expect(helper).to receive(:a_method_from_first_helper).with(expected_args)
      helper.a_method_from_second_helper
    end
  end
end
```

#### Edit

I just realized that your helper is not including the `FirstHelper`, see the `module_eval` block in the example

Comment: I don't seem to need the `module_eval` block - it works without. What I was missing was `helper.a_method_from_second_helper`, rather than just `a_method_from_second_helper` when calling it.